# RGB to CIEXYZ in Java

Tags: java, colors, rgb, color-space

I'm trying to convert **RGB** colors to **CIEXYZ** and eventually would like to convert them to CIELAB however I'm experiencing problems with the *java.awt.color.ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ* Color Space.

Using a calculator online I get different values than the ones provided from the Color Space

Code:

```
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CIEXYZ {

    private final static float[] RGB = new float[] {255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f};
    private final static ColorSpace CIEXYZ = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("RGB: " + Arrays.toString(RGB));
        System.out.println("CIEXYZ: " + Arrays.toString(CIEXYZ.fromRGB(RGB)));
    }
}
```

Output:

> RGB: [255.0, 255.0, 255.0]
>
> CIEXYZ: [0.95254517, 0.98773193, 0.81500244]

Calculator online:

http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=CALC

> XYZ        =   95.050  100.000  108.900

Is there something I am overlooking or doing wrong?

Comment: I thought, that the float range should be 0.0f .. 1.0f. For ints 0 .. 255.

Comment: So I would simply have to divide them by 255.0f?

Comment: When programmers talk about colors, they tend to think: "Well, RGB, right? That's easy". When you dive a bit deeper into this topic, you'll be confronted with the results of 50 years of research about colorimetry (and an odd number of standards and details). E.g. on the calculator website, the white point is "Daylight", whatever that means. The [ColorSpace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html) says that XYZ uses D50. Using this on the website will cause some value to be out of range (Java might clamp it, or simply ignore this and return the value)

Comment: @MicroHat11 yes try to scale to 1.0 or 0.99. Mind that is from memory.

Comment: @JoopEggen It's not that easy. Each color space has its own [min- and max-value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html#getMaxValue-int-) for the individual components (and some of them are not even really strictly defined - it's really odd...).

Comment: @Marco13 RGB was meant; but indeed the boundaries always need attention, hence my initial remark about 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the result of the Java class chromatically adapting to *CIE Standard Illuminant D50*.

Using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour), here is for example a conversion to tristimulus values while keeping the *sRGB* colourspace illuminant (*CIE Standard Illuminant D65*):

```python
import colour

sRGB = np.array([255., 255., 255.])
sRGB /= 255.

# Default conversion from *sRGB* colourspace 
# to *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values.
# It should return *CIE Standard Illuminant D65* 
# tristimulus values using the above array.
print(colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(sRGB))
```

> [ 0.95042854  1.          1.08890037]

and now the same conversion but chromatically adapting to *CIE Standard Illuminant D50*:

```python
# Conversion to *CIE XYZ tristimulus* values but chromatically adapting 
# to *CIE Standard Illuminant D50*.
D50 = colour.ILLUMINANTS['cie_2_1931']['D50']

print(colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(sRGB, D50))
```

> [ 0.96421199  1.          0.82518828]

Usually illuminants are normalised to their *Luminance* which is why *Y* is equal to *1* in our computations, I didn't investigated why the Java class doesn't return the normalised value but a quick check shows that its computation are almost spot on:

```python
D50 = colour.ILLUMINANTS['cie_2_1931']['D50']

print(colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(sRGB, D50) * 0.98773193)
```

> Colour : [ 0.95238297  0.98773193  0.81506482]
>
> Java : [ 0.95254517  0.98773193  0.81500244]